# How to remove Busybox after uninstalling Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, busybox

After trying out linux for a week, I decided to switch back to Windows because of the apps I use daily.

Yesterday I decided to completely reinstall windows for whatever reason, and I noticed the linux distro I was previously using was still an available boot option.

Something I think is noteworthy, is that I screwed up the distro installation; I was at the point of installation where you basically get a sandbox version of the distro to try stuff out. I was tyring to boot from my Windows flash drive and ended up there and so to cancel the installation, I decided to rebooted (not the smartest choice, I know now). I was sent into BusyBox as "initframs". I don't remember exactly but there was an error saying "Missing Modules: [module number]."

I managed to get out using reboot -f and here I am now.

Comment: That's how it work with UEFI. First thing to do - after properly installing Windows -, if it doesn't boot directly is to open UEFI> Boot and change the boot order to "Windows bootloader manager". This is really 101, if you don't know how to manage your firmware settings you shouldn't be installing OSes.

Comment: You haven't really answered my question, I'm asking how to remove it, I have booted into Windows and everything works fine, I just want to know how to remove Busybox.

Comment: If I intended to answer your question I would've posted an answer, not a comment. You actually don't need to remove anything, you need to LEARN how the boot process works with UEFI. According to your description you're still booting the Linux entry. Changing to the Windows bootloader boot Windows directly. Whether or not there are other bootloaders remaining is then immaterial.

Comment: After an firmware update, BusyBox is no more, but it still is a boot option in:
Advanced Startup > Use a device
When I try to boot into it, it just boots windows normally, so it'd be cool if I could remove that.

Comment: Also to clarify, I'm not booting the Linux Entry, I am booting Windows directly, It just showed up as a option, which when booted sent me directly into BusyBox, and that I was asking how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For good practice, follow harrymc's instructions. If you are still having the same issue as me where the OS is still an option in Window's boot menu do:

- Enter Command Prompt as admin
- Enter: `bcdedit /enum firmware`

A list should come up, where hopefully should be the OS you're trying to remove.

- Look for its identifier and then type: `bcdedit /remove {ID}`

And that should hopefully fix it! Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

- Run Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator
- Enter the following commands:

  ```
  mountvol K: /S    (mount the EFI partition as K:)
  K:
  cd EFI
  dir
  ```
- You will see several folders, where one might be called "linux"
  or "busybox". Assuming it's called "linux", enter the following
  command:

  ```
  rd /s linux       (will ask for permissions, allow if seems right)
  mountvol K: /D    (to unmount K)
  ```
- Reboot to check.

Ensure you have full backups and a Windows installation
(or recovery disk) before starting, since an error might cause
Windows to become unbootable or even for data to be lost.

Comment: Or use the freeware EasyUEFI ;)

Comment: When I try to open it, it says access denied and to access it go into security tab, which isn't there in properties.

Comment: Are you referring to my answer or to the comment by ChanganAuto? Please only comment on my answer here.

Comment: Yours, sorry painfully new here.

Comment: You mean that Explorer is refusing to show `K:`?

Comment: Yes, it says Click continue to access this drive, then says permission denied go into security tab to gain access, but security tab isn't there.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work any more, apparently removed in a recent version of Windows 10. I'm rewriting my answer, so just drill down in `diskpart` to the K: partition and enter the command `remove` to delete the drive letter. Then see my rewritten answer.

Comment: Sorry for this extremely late reply, i've tried this and I do not see a directory called linux or anything similar. Though I do see a "Boot" directory, which contains bootx64.efi file, but im guessing its for windows ( there is a seperate Microsoft dir aswell).
Refresher: I can still boot into [ old distro ] as initframs in busybox. It's not available as a boot option in UEFI, but in Advanced Startup > Boot from USB

Comment: I've figure it out. Thanks for your help harrymc! I'm sure it'll come useful when I've done something stupid again.